# Как отключить ограничение на шорткоды в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, шорткод

На сайте много шорткодов. Неожиданно страницы перестали отображаться. Вычитал, что у Wordpress ограничение на 100 шорткодов. можно ли как то отключить?

Comment: смотрите логи. может там не ограничения, а просто скрипт отваливается

Comment: Не читай чернокнижников. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710

Comment: Чушь какая. Нет такого ограничения. Запомните автора этого перла и больше никогда его не читайте.